# why div not taking width of 90% of the total width?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, styled-components

Could you please tell me why div not taking a width of 90% of total width? When I write like that

```
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
```

it takes the width, but when I write like this it doesn't

```
display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
```

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-dawn-o6rx2

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: "90%";
  /* // width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto; */
`;
```

how to center form vertically and horizontally

Comment: It takes the 90% width you need inspect div first that you styling it.

Comment: I think that your containing div should have the defined width first and then the wrapper inside it will take the width 90% of that parent div. So try defining the width of the container first and then its child ( Wrapper )

Comment: You can use inline CSS as an object like this `style={{Width: "90%", display: "flex",justifyContent: "center",alignItems: "center", height: "100vh"
      }}`

Comment: how to `center form vertically and horizontally`

Comment: "90%" should be 90%

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing everything correct except a single line:

Change this line

```
width: "90%";
```

to this one

```
width: 90%;
```

So your final CSS will be

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto; */
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS of your styled Wrapper component should be like the example below. Notice that in your example you have double quotes around 90% which is an invalid CSS value. It has to be 90% without double quotes since styled components use regular CSS syntax.

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 90%; //<=== here
  margin: 0 auto;
`;
```

and you will need to give your form 100% width if you want it to use 100% of the wrapper

```
const StyledForm = styled.form`
width: 100%;
`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `width: "90%";` to `width: 90%;`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Yes the double quotes and " <code>" after div -- style.div</code> might create a problem]

```css
.testingWidth{
  display:flex;
  flex-basis:100%;
  width:90%;
  max-width:90%;
  min-width:90%;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:#CCAACC;
  min-height:10vh;
  padding:0.125em;
}
```

```html
<div class="testingWidth">
styling with class.

</div>


<div style="display:flex;flex-basis:100%;width:90%;max-width:90%;min-width:90%;margin:0 auto;background-color:#CCC;min-height:10vh;padding:0.125em;">
styling without class.

<p>Do add flex-basis to your styling and check again.</p>
</div>
```